# Elixir Stream.unfold setting up new state

Tags: elixir

Here's an example of displaying a fibonacci sequence with elixir using `Stream.unfold`.

```
Stream.unfold({0,1}, fn {f1,f2} -> {f1, {f2, f1+f2}} end) |> Enum.take(15)

[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377]
```

**Why** does it require to provide `f1` in `{f1, {f2, f1+f2}}` and not just `{f2, f1+f2}`?

Because in the explanation of the code above author says:

> The new state moves one down the sequence, so an initial state of
>   {f1,f2} becomes a new state of {f2,f1+f2}.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `f1` is the value that should be yielded by the stream to the consumer while `{f2, f1 + f2}` is the *state* the unfold operation needs for the next iteration. Generating Fibonacci numbers requires 2 values in the state to work.

If you were generating natural numbers instead, you could do with a tuple of 2 integers:

```
iex(1)> Stream.unfold(0, fn x -> {x, x + 1} end) |> Enum.take(10)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Excuse me, so in the following part `{f1, {f2, f1+f2}}` - `f1 = f2(of the current iteration)` and  `f2 = f1+f2(for the next iteration)`, right? (Basically it's just nested)

Comment: Yep, if the state is `{a, b}`, the next state is `{b, a + b}`, and the value to yield right now is `a`. (`a` and `b` are a little easier to follow than `f1` and `f2` IMO.)